# AppleScript working until placed in cron; causing Chrome to go unresponsive

Tags: macos, applescript, google-chrome, cron

Good afternoon.  Question: I have a simple apple script telling Google Chrome to open,
go to a URL, and enter presentation mode...

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    make new window
    set myURL to "http://myURL.php"
    tell window 1 to make new tab with properties {URL:myURL}
    tell window 1 to enter presentation mode
end tell
```

Running in AppleScript editor, it behaves correctly.  From CLI, it also behaves
correctly...

```
/usr/bin/osascript /<fqpn>/openURL.scpt
```

but if I take that snippet and put it in my cron, it fails to go to fullscreen and Chrome becomes unresponsive, requiring a force quit.  I get the following error in /var/mail:

```
/<fqpn>/openURL.scpt:725:748: execution error: Google Chrome got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

I have no ~/.* files on this account (OSX 10.9.2), so I tried sourcing my /etc/profile first in my crontab, but no effect.

Any ideas what my problem is?

-Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same applescript; I moved over to launchd; using a generic template pulled from

[http://launched.zerowidth.com/](http://launched.zerowidth.com/plists/2535b2d0-853e-0131-890d-62e874135003)

and everything behaved just as expected.  I'm not sure *what* I was missing in my cron environment; but the answer seems to be to avoid crontabs for simple applescripts for now..